# CSS3 transform not working properly on iOS (and maybe other mobile devices)

Tags: ios, html, css, transform

I'm doing my school project on web design, and I'm having a css3 transform problem (or something that I don't know) on iOS.

This is the link for my demo website: http://lovelyiris.byethost17.com/

The problem is: (I'll say it step by step here)

- You can see the tab "New Arrivals" at the bottom, right ?
- On PC, when you click that tab, the New Arrivals page will appear with the stack-like photo album, and when you click the arrow, the image will change with some css3 transform effect. (just go to my website and test it).
- And here's the problem on my devices - ipod touch gen 3 and ipad 2:

  - First, the album doesn't appear when I tap on "New Arrivals" tab. But when I go to another tab then go back to "New Arrivals" again, the album appears (ie: Home -> New Arrivals -> About -> New Arrivals)
  - After the album appeared, when I tap the arrow, the album disappears again. And if I go to another tab and then go back, the album is back again, with the last image there!

(You can test this on you device).

So, I think that the photo album is still working, but in a wrong way. It just scroll  from the first to the last image, not showing anything in between, like it worked on the PC.

This is the HTML for the "New Arrivals" tab:

```
<section class="st-panel st-color" id="st-panel-2">
   <div class="st-deco" data-icon="*"></div>
   <h2 id="newarr">New Arrivals</h2>
   <section class="main">
       <ul id="st-stack" class="st-stack-raw">
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/001.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 1</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/002.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 2</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/003.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 3</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 4</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 5</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 6</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 7</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 8</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 9</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
          <li><div class="st-item"><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" width="400" height="300"/></a></div><div class="st-title"><h2>Dress 10</h2><h3>in Dress Category</h3></div></li>
       </ul>
    </section>
 </section>
```

And the css is [here](http://lovelyiris.byethost17.com/css/stack.css). (sorry, it's a long file)

So, what did I do wrong ?

And I wonder whether it's the same on other OS (android...) or not ?

Thank you. And sorry for my bad english.